# Flutter error: The argument type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>? can't be assigned to parameter 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-futurebuilder

I get this Errorcode when I try to run my flutter app and I don't know how to solve it please help:

> Error: The argument type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>?' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>' because
> 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>?' is nullable and
> 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>' isn't.
>
> - 'DocumentSnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'
>   ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-3.1.0/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>
>   ```
>    MyUser user = MyUser.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
>                                               ^
>   ```

This is my useresRef:

```
final CollectionReference usersRef =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
```

And this is the Widget I'm trying to build:

```
Widget buildProfileHeader(context) {

    final myuser = Provider.of<MyUser>(context);

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: usersRef.doc(myuser.id).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return circularProgress();
        }
        MyUser user = MyUser.fromDocument(snapshot.data);

        return Row(...)
```

This is the MyUser Factory:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class MyUser{
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String displayName;
  final String username;

  MyUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.photoUrl,
    required this.displayName,
    required this.username,
  });

  factory MyUser.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return MyUser(
        id: doc['id'].toString(),
        username: doc['username'].toString(),
        email: doc['email'].toString(),
        photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'].toString(),
        displayName: doc['displayName'].toString(),
    );
  }
```

I don't understand how i could fix that issue. I tried using snapshot.data.data(), however while it fixed my current error it gave me the new error message:

> error: The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the
> receiver can be 'null'. (unchecked_use_of_nullable_value at
> [flutter_app] lib\pages\profile_screen.dart:58)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuu just need to use :

```
MyUser user = MyUser.fromDocument(snapshot.data!);
```

because at this point in your code, even if you tested `snapshot.hasData`, dart is telling you that data could be null... But you already handled this case, so it's ok to add a `!`